# Is there a template creation Event in Darts Web_ui?

Tags: dart, dart-webui

Is there anything like a notification mechanism for the instantiation of a template?

Assume the following simple template:

```html
<template iterate="name in names"> 
  <div>{{name}}</div>
</template>
```

When a name is very long, it might be possible that the container of the name `div` is overflown. So what I would like to do is to get an event when the name `div` is added to the DOM so that I can take a look at the resulting width. I would then shorten the name until it fits nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: I assume you can't achieve what you want with CSS. So here's a code solution.

I am not aware of any event or a way to hook into the creation process.

However, I have done something like this with success:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
```

```dart
inserted() {
  Timer.run(() {
    // Do your calculations here...
  });
}
```

If you set your `name` variable later, then you could alternatively make it observable and set the timer after the value changes:

```dart
observe(() => name), (_) {
  Timer.run(() {
    // Recalculate...
  });
});
```

And remember to mark it `@observable` and set the listener in `created()`.

Comment: The `inserted()` does not help me as the name is contained within another WebComponent. But triggering on modification did do the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

You should really handle something like this in CSS:

```css
.name {
  width: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

And give your div a class of `name`.

This will automatically shrink the text down to the container width and add an ellipsis to indicate that the text has been truncated.

Comment: I did not know about the text-overflow: ellipsis, so thanks for that. Unfortunately that does not help me here because it truncates at the end. And the last few characters are the one that are actually the most interesting...